# RabbitMq - Channels and Connections not closing

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm using the following Nodejs script to publish messages in my RabbitMq queue:

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");
[...]

const publishMsgToQueue = async (job, res) => {
  const queue = job.queueName;
  const msg = { url: job.msg };

  try {
    const connection = await amqp.connect(Rabbitmq.host);
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: true });
    await channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)));

    await channel.close();
    await connection.close();

  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(
      "[AMQP] Error publishing to RabbitMQ",
      job.msg,
      "queue name:",
      job.queueName
    );
  }
};
```

This function is called in a `for` loop to publish an array of messages.

When all the messages are published, I have many many connections and channels open... while it should be closed thanks to channel.close and connection.close ... but it's not...

I check a lot on other posts, but I didn't succeed so far...

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: How are you calling `for` loop? Based on what you have above those connections would only linger around if there were some errors prior to you closing the the `channel` and `connection`. Try putting `close` calls in `finally` block instead. Also, just as a good practice it's good to start only one connection instead of starting brand new connection on each of your msg as you saw it can overwhelm the server.

Comment: @shriek is correct. It is VERY INEFFICIENT to open a new connection and channel per-message. Do NOT do that!!!!